# How to get hsqldb-2.7.1-jdk8.jar from maven central repository

Tags: gradle, hsqldb

I have jdk-8 in my local, and I using gradle to build my project. I try to update my hsqldb from version 2.5.2 to 2.7.1. After I update my gradle script:

```
runtime "org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.5.2"
```

to

```
runtime "org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.7.1"
```

Then I build with gradle but it download the java-11 version. Which led an UnsupportedClassVersionError in my project. I found there is a java-8 version in the maven central repository https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.7.1/.But it will not be downloaded automatically.

I wish can update hsqldb to the latest version, then run gradle build and  it can download the correct version. And I can run my project sucessfully.

Answer (score 9):

You need to provide the classifier, which is jdk8 in this case. In your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <classifier>jdk8</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I know you asked for Gradle but it is the same principle.

Comment: Glad to learn something new, thank you very much!

Comment: a vote would be nice :)

Comment: Sorry, I tried at first but not have enough reputation to cast a vote

Answer (score 2):

you can add classifier to your implementation like this

```
runtime "org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.7.1:jdk8"
```

And you can make sure its added with `gradle dependencies`

it will show you

```
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
\--- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.7.1

testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
\--- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.7.1
```